# Jquery - Internet Explorer - Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this site and in Internet Explorer I get this syntax error in IE only, Chrome its fine.

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: communities.js, Line: 157, Column: 55
```

Line 157 is this: `priceArray = priceArray.filter(x => x != $(this).val());`

Here is the whole code, but IE wont tell me what the syntax error is.

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {

            if ($(this).attr("id") == 'price') {
                if (this.checked) {
                    priceArray.push($(this).val());
                }
                else {
                    priceArray = priceArray.filter(x => x != $(this).val());
                }
            }
});
});
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

priceArray is defined at the top of the file:

```
var priceArray = [];
```

Comment: IE does not support arrow functions (`x => ...`) - [Source](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: ahhhhh man! what is an alternative to fixing this?

Comment: Using a normal function, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Santi pointed out in the comments, IE does not support arrow functions.

The solution is to use a normal function. Normal functions however have their own `this` object, so you have to give `filter` the object that the provided function should be called with:

```js
// ...
priceArray = priceArray.filter(function (x) {
  return x !== $(this).val();
}, this);
// ...
```

Comment: Just to add-on here (as I mentioned in the comments on the post itself), the reason it didn't work in the first place is because [IE does not support `=>` (arrow functions)](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).